# How to create new fields for customer registration in magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento, field

I am developing a website with magento ver-1.9.2. I am try to create new fields for customer registration, but it not created.

Please Help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow this website for create new field in customer registration

[Example](http://www.danneh.org/2011/07/adding-new-attribute-to-customer-account-in-magento/)

You can add this [Extension](https://marketplace.magento.com/zestardtech-customerattributes.html)

Comment: i use this example but i don't have any result.

Comment: have you install that extension?

Comment: ya i installed that extension and it's working for me thanks.